# Masking 3d object from background

Tags: animation, blender-internal-render-engine, masking, compositing-nodes, movie-clip-editor

I have a 3d object placed on top of the movie clip. The problem is i used a third part motion tracker and so the movie clip editor doesn't load the movie clip so how will i able to mask the background??

Comment: Render Properties>>Film>>Transparency (EEVEE) or Transparent (Cycles)

Comment: Nop that doesnt work